# get the id value of a tag i tag closest to input using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have the code like as below.

```
<input type="text" id="commentInput" >
<a class="Comment" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#commentModal"><i style="font-size: 30px;margin-left: 30px;" class="fa fa-comment-o" id="ficon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Below is the jquery which i m trying

```
var id = $('commentInput').closest('a').find('i').attr('id');
```

But i m not getting the `id value` . its throwing as `undefined` .
Any suggestions please .

Comment: You're missing the id selector prefix. `$('commentInput')` --> `$('#commentInput')`

Comment: Also the input-control you are trying to find is not a child of your comment-element, so the closest-function call will not find that a-element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, you're missing the `#` on the id selector in your jQuery object. Secondly, `closest()` is used to look up the DOM at the parents of the element. The `a` is a sibling of the `input`, so you could use `next()` instead. Try this:

```js
var id = $('#commentInput').next('a').find('i').prop('id');

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="commentInput">
<a class="Comment" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal">
  <i style="font-size: 30px;margin-left: 30px;" class="fa fa-comment-o" id="ficon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```